# How to get all the logs with certain string value in the last a few minutes

Tags: shell, date, awk

I have an application using its own log file format. Now I want to get all the lines of logs with certain string values such as "Fatal error" within a certain period of time. The log data format is like the following:

```
Thread-28689296: Thu Aug 25 15:18:41 2016 [ info ]: abcd efddf 
Thread-28689296: Thu Aug 25 15:19:01 2016 [ info ]: xvbdfdre dfdfd 
Thread-28689296: Thu Aug 25 15:19:11 2016 [ info ]: Fatal error 
Thread-28689296: Thu Aug 25 15:19:41 2016 [ info ]: dfdfdfd
```

If "now" is Aug 25 15:19:41 2016, I want to find between 15:19:41 and 15:17:41 those lines that have "Fatal error" in my log file. So the current time should be from date and x minutes ago should be from "date x minutes ago" to find certain error messages from the application log.

If I use the following command line:

```
  awk -v Date="$(date "+%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")" -v Date2="$(date -- date="2 
  minutes ago" "+%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")" '$5 > Date && $5 < Date2' log_file | 
  grep "Fatal error"
```

the variable "$5" in the condition actually gets the value of minute "17" and "19" in my sample log data but it compares with a date value. So this won't work.

How can I construct the value of time in log timestamp from $3 to $7 fields to compare the value of current time. I m not so familiar with shell scripting.

Thanks for your advice and help in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest to convert the `$3` to `$7` fields to another format, a fixed-length one, easier to compare or sort. My preferred is **`YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:SS`** (or **`%F %T`**)

Comment: No my problem is that I need to construct value from data field from $3 to $7 in order to compare with the current time. I don't know if the constructed value can be directed used in the comparison condision or should I write another shell func to handle that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
#!/bin/sh

  Date="$(date "+%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")"
  Date2="$(date --date="2 minutes ago" "+%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")"

  first_line=$(grep -n "$Date2" log_file | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')

  last_line=$(grep -n "$Date" log_file | awk -F ":" '{print $1}')

  sed -n "${first_line},${last_line}p" log_file | grep "Fatal error"
```

Comment: I ran your script, I got this error "sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `,' ". I checked the regular expression syntax at [link] (https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html). It says " \{i,j\} Matches between i and j, inclusive, sequences. " So comma should be okay in your case. I a  not familar with sed  and regular expression either. Do you have a clue of the error from my execution of your script? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You got the error because  the $first_line  & $last_line are empty.They did not get any values from the commands at lines 4-5 of the script.

Comment: You said : "I want to find between 15:19:41 and 15:17:41"
--> Do you really need to compare in seconds ? or just  15:19 and 15:17

Comment: no,  actually second can be ignored in my case. Yes, because of the second value, it never gets right values as sed parameters, so you are right. I have figured it our the problem already but with awk script for another test. so Date="$(date "+%%H:%M:)"
  Date2="$(date --date="2 minutes ago" "+%H:%M:")" Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One in Gnu AWK:

```
$ cat > check.awk 
BEGIN {
    start=mktime("2016 8 25 15 19 00") # desired start time. If now, use something like:
    # end=strftime("%s"); start=end-120
    end=mktime("2016 8 25 15 19 12")   # end time for this example
    # make text months into numbers:
    split("Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec",mons,",")
    for(i in mons)
        mons[mons[i]]=i
}
{
    atime=mktime($6" "mons[$3]" "$4" "gensub(/:/," ","g",$5)) # your log time format
} 
atime<end && atime>start # && add your desired error messages here
$ awk -f check.awk yer.log
Thread-28689296: Thu Aug 25 15:19:01 2016 [ info ]: xvbdfdre dfdfd
Thread-28689296: Thu Aug 25 15:19:11 2016 [ info ]: Fatal error
```