# Howto grep over months with defined start and end date

Tags: regex, bash, date, grep

so here's my problem: I have big log files and want a script to grep certain periods of time and safe them to a file (sorted), basically

```
bash script.sh Jul 4 Sep 30
```

will return for example

```
Sep 30 user0 logged in
Sep 15 user1 logged in
Aug 6 user0 logged in
Aug 3 user1 logged in
Jul 28 user2 logged in
Jul 27 user2 logged in
Jul 4 user0 logged in
```

My first attempt was that every month and date gets his own variable like

```
bash script.sh Jul 4 Sep 3 0
```

so I can use $1 for start month (July), $2 for start date (4) and so on in grep like

```
for logs in logs*
do
grep -qEe "^\"$1\" [\"$2\"-9]\s" $messages >> result.txt
done
```

to get all logs from July 4 to 9 but I don't know how to get logs from the entire time period that aren't in the same month nor in a period like 1-9 or 10-19 and so on
Any help greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
As some people asked, here's how my log files look like (just much bigger and not sorted):

```
Sep 30 user0 logged in
Jul 27 user2 logged in
Aug 6 user0 logged in
Aug 31 user1 logged in
Jul 8 user2 logged in
Sep 5 user1 logged in
Jul 27 user2 logged in
Jul 14 user0 logged in
[...]
```

Comment: Give us a few lines from the log file as an example.

Comment: Here's one in Gnu awk: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39220666/how-to-get-all-the-logs-with-certain-string-value-in-the-last-a-few-minutes/39221519#39221519

Comment: the log files looks like the second code segment, just with much more lines (unsorted) with other dates like Jul 3 user 0 logged in or May 15 user 1 logged in

Comment: @JamesBrown I'm not familiar with awk and altough the question is similar there's no explanation to this solution

Comment: Lol, set your desired start and end times as commented and this is your `mktime` row near the end: `mktime("2016 "mons[$1]" "$2" 00 00 00")` but of course out-of-box is easier. Just trying to help.

Comment: @JamesBrown didn't mean to offend you, I just don't know awk at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take:

```
#/bin/bash

year="$(date +"%Y")"
start="$(date -d"$1 $2, $year" +'%s')"
end="$(($(date -d"$3 $4, $year" +'%s')+86400))"
for log in logs*; do
    while IFS= read -r line; do
        d="$(date -d"$(cut -d' ' -f1,2 <<< "$line"), $year" +'%s')"
        if (( $start <= $d && $d < $end )); then
            echo "$s"
        fi
    done < "$log"
done
```

You run it like that: `./script.sh Jul 04 Sep 03`. Since no year is included in the logs, it assumes that all dates (including the ones in the command line) are for the current year. It's probably not the most optimal solution but it works. It relies on `date` which it repeatedly calls to parse dates into a unix timestamp. unix timestamps are nice because they are just numbers and thus can be used in numeric comparisons.

Comment: Thank you this looks very near to what I want. Hm but I don't understand lines 5 & 6 (d= , I think this is to convert the date and time in the logs?) could u explain them? Also because my logs look different then Thu Aug 25 15:19:01 2016 [ info ]: xvbdfdre dfdfd (no day names nor time and year) :/

Comment: I cannot help you if you don't give an example of a line from the log. The lines of code that you don't understand, do string manipulations to extract the date part of the string and the parse it.

Comment: the log files look like the second code segment, just with much more lines (unsorted) with other dates like Jul 3 user 0 logged in or May 15 user 1 logged in (I edited my post so everybody can see it)

Comment: I got it almost working now BUT I saw that the lines with a single digit like "Aug 8" do have two (!) whitespaces, like Aug--6 user0 logged in instead of Aug-6 user0 logged in (I used - for whitespace to show, in the logs there are no - between Aug and 8). The problem is cut uses a single whitespace as separator between field one and two.. any idea how to work around this?

Comment: ok I found a solution using trimm, something like `date +%-m%d -d "$(tr -s ' ' <<< "Jul  5 jkxjkakjb" | cut -d' ' -f1,2)"` which transforms Aug--6 user0 logged in to of Aug-6 (I used - for whitespace to show, in the logs there are no - between Aug and 6) and then calculates to a date mdd in this case `705`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ range="Jul 4 Sep 30"
$ awk -v range="$range" '
BEGIN {
    numMths = split("Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",m)
    for (i in m) {
        mths[m[i]] = i
    }

    split(range,r)
    beg = sprintf("%02d%02d", mths[r[1]], r[2])
    end = sprintf("%02d%02d", mths[r[3]], r[4])
}
{ cur = sprintf("%02d%02d", mths[$1], $2) }
(cur >= beg) && (cur <= end) { vals[$1,$2] = $0 }
END {
    for (mthNr=numMths; mthNr>0; mthNr--) {
        for (dayNr=31; dayNr>0; dayNr--) {
            date = m[mthNr] SUBSEP dayNr
            if (date in vals) {
                print vals[date]
            }
        }
    }
}
' file
Sep 30 user0 logged in
Sep 5 user1 logged in
Aug 31 user1 logged in
Aug 6 user0 logged in
Jul 27 user2 logged in
Jul 14 user0 logged in
Jul 8 user2 logged in
```